# Android - Passing data to a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, proximity

In my Android app, i'm implementing a position-based notification service. In order to do so, i have implemented the following method:

```
private void addProximityAlert() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    for(int i=0; i<tappe.size(); i++) {  //<--- tappe is an ArrayList<Object>

        if(tappe.get(i).Lat != -1.00 && tappe.get(i).Lon != -1.00) {   //<--- i'm checking if fields Latitude and Longitude are valid
            double latitude = tappe.get(i).Lat;
            double longitude = tappe.get(i).Lon;

                locationManager.addProximityAlert(
                        latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
                        longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
                        POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
                        PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration
                        proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
                );

        }
    }

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

    registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);  //<--- i want to pass my object to ProximityIntentReceiver(which extends BroadcastReceiver) 

}
```

Now i want to pass the i-th object "tappe" to my ProximityIntentReceiver(which extends BroadcastReceiver) if the object position matches the proximity condition. How can i do ?

Comment: Have your "Object" extend `Serializable`?

Comment: implements Parcellable